# Android studio error: An error occurred while trying to compute required packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying to install the latest Android Studio on a MacBook pro 2015

Unfortunately I get this error:

> An error occurred while trying to compute required packages.

Here a screenshot of the error:

[image]

which is not very informative. What's causing the problem?

**EDIT**

This is the exception I get when I run the application from the terminal:

```
[  33666]   WARN - e.wizard.InstallComponentsPath - Dependant package with key emulator not found! 
com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils$PackageResolutionException: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.SdkQuickfixUtils.resolve(SdkQuickfixUtils.java:261)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.install.ComponentInstaller.getPackagesToInstall(ComponentInstaller.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallComponentsPath.lambda$init$0(InstallComponentsPath.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallSummaryStep.generateSummary(InstallSummaryStep.java:115)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.InstallSummaryStep.onEnterStep(InstallSummaryStep.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.next(DynamicWizardPath.java:311)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizardPath.next(DynamicWizardPath.java:58)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.showNextStep(DynamicWizard.java:346)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.doNextAction(DynamicWizard.java:336)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.wizard.FirstRunWizardHost$NextAction.actionPerformed(FirstRunWizardHost.java:385)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

**EDIT**

Google [has fixed the bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42743644/958464). Just download the new installer and everything should be fine

Comment: I'm suddenly getting the same problem. I can't seemingly install Android Studio have just deleted it and trying to re-install it. I've even tried installing version 2.2.0 but the same problem.

Comment: do you know if there are any log files to look for?

Comment: Not really. I've deleted all working directories and tried again, but nothing is working. Hopefully someone will have a solution to this soon ... as it's pretty frustrating. It was working yesterday. Then, when it tried to update to the latest version, I started having MAJOR problems saying it couldn't update due to conflicts - hence uninstalling and trying to re-install. I'll not be doing that again any time soon!

Comment: posted the question on twitter... @androiddeveloper

Comment: It may be a temporary outage of some server (I hope)

Comment: Same issue. Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Same here. Linux Mint.

Comment: Terminal output says "Dependant package with key emulator not found!", not much of a hint I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dependant package with key emulator not found while updating android SDK and tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732684/dependant-package-with-key-emulator-not-found-while-updating-android-sdk-and-too)

Comment: Try installing Android Studio without AVD

Comment: Looks like the issue is resolved. No workaround is needed anymore.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**

**There's a manual workaround!**

As per post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733510/7694425 :

1. Download the command line tools, place them in the SDK folder (e.g.,
   on mac: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk), and then add the bin
   folder to the PATH.
2. Install the latest platform: in a terminal,
   execute sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
3. Open Android Studio, and
   go to the SDK Manager (Appearance and Behavior > System Settings >
   Android SDK)
4. Click on "Edit", and then select the sdk folder. Then
   "Next" > "Next" > "Finish".

Still, it doesn't resolve the missing emulator package therefore the Android SDK tools can't be updated since it's a dependency. But Android studio works and you can download other packages.

Looking forward to a better solution.

**Update 2:**

**Solution to emulator package issue!**

After digging in the repo's XML for a while I've spotted the issue.

It turns out that the "emulator" package is only in channel 3 (canary) while the "tools" package is in channel 0 (stable) but depends on "emulator". The solution is to force the manager to download the "emulator" package from channel 3:

```
./sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator
```

Problem solved!

**Previous answer:**

The same problem here.

Twitted @androidstudio too. Hopefully someone in a position to fix this will notice.

Comment: @gianlucaghettini Did you manage to update Android SDK Tools?

Comment: The CLI tools only work when they're in the sub-directory named 'tools'. (eg. /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk/tools) - so don't move them out of the directory in the .ZIP!

Comment: @Charlie_Mtz Thanks for help! In my case I had to additionally install SDK Platform-tools since they were not install after applying the workaround.

Comment: @KrzysztofKansy I executed the installation wizard after running the sdkmanager since I had deleted every trace of Android Studio in my computer in an attempt to force it to behave. I guess that's what would download the platform tools among other initialisation.

Comment: On Ubuntu the configure button was hidden, so I had to change my Display scaling to get the button so I could change the SDK location

Comment: Solution to emulator package issue! is solved thank you http://stackoverflow.com/a/42737696/5133603

Comment: Update 3: this should be fixed on the server side now (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=244956)

Comment: It is said to download the command line tools. But from where shall I download the supposed command line tools? The Android Studio site only contains different versions of Android Studio for Windows, Mac, Linux and Chrome OS. I don't see any command line tools there. Can someone please clarify? Also, please explain how to execute sdkmanager in Windows 7 command prompt. Shall I run it in the default prompt of CMD, or shall I have to cd to some other directory? Android Studio's installation process is undesirably complicated. Google must look into it.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated: It should be fixed now.**

This is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=244956 -- we're working on a hotfix.

Answer (score 2):

After lot of struggling I made it work.
Here my solution

When I get the "An error occurred while trying to compute required packages" error I just clicked "finished" and then I went to the main Android Studio page:

[image]

Then I selected Configure -> SDK manager and I launched the SDK installation from there

Reopened Android Studio and everything was ok

Really, really embarrassing for a software which used to be very good. You can feel the "bloatness" of Eclipse creeping in

Comment: Not working this way... When I select SDK manager and try to click on Android SDK 'Edit' link, SDK Android name appears, I click Next, and same error occurs...

Answer (score 1):

Install these packages and then check it and also set `JAVA_HOME` for `jdk`.
It worked for me. For more information see this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html).

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the setup again, it's working now, I am able to install it.

Answer (score 1):

This workaround worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69868954/6809733

> Just download the IDE - Intellij IDEA and create a new project, select Android Project and there download Android SDK, now you can install android studio again and the sdk is installed. Worked for me!

Comment: I confirm that this is the correct answer for MBP Pro (M1 Pro). 
If you got the "Dependant package with key emulator not found!" error while trying to start Android Studio, this answer will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on Arch Linux because the SDK setup wizard ran out of space on `/tmp`, which is a `tmpfs`.

Another question with a similar error and same possible cause: [Android studio- “SDK tools directory is missing”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45942084/21501)