# Problem occuring when trying to install Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I'm trying to install android studio on my 32 bit Windows 10 computer, it says that an error occurred while trying to compute required packages. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio error: An error occurred while trying to compute required packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733995/android-studio-error-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-compute-required-package)

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Download the Java SE Developement Kit ([Directdownload for 32Bit](https://www.oracle.com/ch-de/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html#license-lightbox)) and install it.
2. After that you can access [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads) on it's site choosing the **No .exe installer** version:

[image: No.Installer]

3. Extract it and go into the **bin** folder and execute **studio.exe** (this is for 32bit).

PS: The **studio64.exe** is **ONLY** recommend for **64bit machines**.

---

This will work! I bet you have installed the wrong Android Studio Version. So uninstall your current Android studio and follow the steps above. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry It didn't work :( The same error still appeared