# M1 MacBook Pro Android Studio Installation Issue - No SDK being downloaded

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1

I am trying to setup Android Studio on my refurbished M1 MBP. I am getting stuck in Android Studio Setup Wizard where it is giving me an error. Another thing I notice is there is no Android/sdk directory created in my Library folder when I install Android Studio. So during installation, the sdk is not being downloaded. I have spent hours on this and haven't been able to find this scenario online. Shouldn't this just work out-of-box? What am I missing here?

I downloaded from https://developer.android.com/studio (Mac with Apple chip - android-studio-2020.3.1.25-mac_arm.zip)

[image]

Comment: Update : BumbleBee Beta gives same issue. Chipmunk Canary works! However, this is not the ideal outcome as "stable" should work...

Comment: I am also facing the same issue... How did you fix it?

Comment: Chipmunk Canary gives me the same error as OP

Answer (score 21):

Just download the IDE - Intellij IDEA and create a new project, select Android Project and there download Android SDK, now you can install android studio again and the sdk is installed. Worked for me!

Comment: I just want to point out that while this seems like a terrible answer, it's not, because it actually works.

Comment: I confirm that this is the correct answer for MBP Pro (M1 Pro). If you got the "Dependant package with key emulator not found!" error while trying to start Android Studio, this answer will solve your problem :)

Comment: I was also having the same issue, and I confirm this is also working for MacBook Pro M1, don't know why but this seems to be not correct flow. Still this work. 
Thanks - it saved my time

Answer (score 4):

As @bjjdroid suggested I have installed the Version Chipmunk Canary 3 which installed the SDK just fine. Afterwards I installed Arctic Fox again and it just used the SDK from the other installer.

Answer (score 0):

### I had the same problem

### SOLUTION:

1. download final version preview (no install)
2. download java for your mac and install
3. download JDK final version java for your mac and install
4. download JRE final version java for your mac and install
5. create in Users/USER_NAME/Library.  Folders... "/Android/sdk"
6. you can install android studio now.

---

NOTES:

*** first install of AndroidStudio.

*** if you install AndroidSutdio before java, SDK, JRE AND FOLDERS... is possible that this is not util