# Android Studio error on Ubuntu: An error occurred while trying to compute required packages

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have followed the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) on the official site.

But I am unable to install Android Studio. I'm getting error message "An error occurred while trying to compute required packages" as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Few months back when I tried to install Android Studio there are instruction in Android Studio official webpage to install Java JDK. Today I don't find any traces about it. Do I need to install any Java related file to fix the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dependant package with key emulator not found while updating android SDK and tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732684/dependant-package-with-key-emulator-not-found-while-updating-android-sdk-and-too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to install the Java Development Kit.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

... e.g. in the terminal should do the trick.

EDIT:

**There's a manual workaround!**

As per post https://stackoverflow.com/a/42733510/7694425 :

1. Download the command line tools, place them in the SDK folder (e.g.,
   on mac: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk), and then add the bin
   folder to the PATH.
2. Install the latest platform: in a terminal,
   execute sdkmanager "platforms;android-25"
3. Open Android Studio, and
   go to the SDK Manager (Appearance and Behavior > System Settings >
   Android SDK)
4. Click on "Edit", and then select the sdk folder. Then
   "Next" > "Next" > "Finish".

Still, it doesn't resolve the missing emulator package therefore the Android SDK tools can't be updated since it's a dependency. But Android studio works and you can download other packages.

Looking forward to a better solution.

**Update 2:**

**Solution to emulator package issue!**

After digging in the repo's XML for a while I've spotted the issue.

It turns out that the "emulator" package is only in channel 3 (canary) while the "tools" package is in channel 0 (stable) but depends on "emulator". The solution is to force the manager to download the "emulator" package from channel 3:

```
./sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Didn't worked. 

First I tried the above command you shared. I got error.

Then i tried below command and installed jdk 9 and after your edit I installed jdk 8.

sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install openjdk-9-jdk

But the problem not solved.

Comment: Look at the post again.