# Unable to install Android build-tools with sdkmanager

Tags: android, command-line

I'm trying to build android applications with the command line tools in Windows 10.
I was able to install the platform tools and the platform with the sdkmanager with no problem and also accepted all of the licenses.

But when I try to install the build tools using this command
`./sdkmanager --sdk_root=C:/Android --verbose "build-tools;27.0.3"` it fails and
I get these messages running on verbose:

```
Info: Parsing C:\Android\cmdline-tools\4.0\package.xml
Info: Parsing C:\Android\platform-tools\package.xml
Info: File C:\Users\PC\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.
```

I found this question which had the same warning: [Error "Dependent package with key emulator not found" while updating Android SDK and tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732684/error-dependent-package-with-key-emulator-not-found-while-updating-android-sdk)

But it seems that the emulator package doesn't exist anymore and I don't think it has to do with why I am unable to install the build-tools

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I ended up installing the build-tools from this website https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools, however I still don't know why it refused to install with the sdkmanager

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the bin folder
2. On the location bar at the top, remove everything for it and type cmd
3. Now type this command:-
   sdkmanager.bat "build-tools;latest" --sdk_root=../
4. After this command, type this command:-
   sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-32" --sdk_root=../

**NOTE - Upper command android-32.0.0 is based on the time I am typing this**

And this will work in most the cases, or try reinstalling or consider watching the video tutorials on YouTube